# Set list of config nodes as value entries in yaml contrasting with structured configs in Hydra

Tags: fb-hydra

I would like to get a list of configs as a (default) value entry
and use a structured schema to validate the input list.

E.g., in `trainer.yaml`:

```
defaults:
  - callbacks:
    - checkpointer
    - early_stopping
```

In `callbacks/checkpointer.yaml` and `callbacks/early_stopping.yaml` I have a link to appropriate structured configs as default values, e.g.:

```
# callbacks/checkpointer.yaml
defaults:
  - /trainer_lib/callbacks/base_checkpointer@_here_
```

The structured schema:

```
@dataclass
class CheckpointerConfig:
    _target_: str = "some_library_class"
    data_dir: str = "folder"

@dataclass
class TrainerConfig:
   callbacks: List[Any] = MISSING
```

and config store:

```
cs = ConfigStore.instance()
cs.store(group="trainer_lib/callbacks", name="base_checkpointer", node=CheckpointerConfig)
```

I am not sure what is the correct syntax (what I tried fails) to accomplish this. I get an `omegaconf.errors.ConfigTypeError: Cannot merge DictConfig with ListConfig`.

Is there a way to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discussion on this topic in this [Hydra issue](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/1389).

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Hydra 1.0? This is actually supported in Hydra 1.1. Here is the documentation: https://hydra.cc/docs/next/patterns/select_multiple_configs_from_config_group

Comment: I am not sure what I am missing. I get an "omegaconf.errors.ConfigTypeError: Cannot merge DictConfig with ListConfig". It might be because the default value in "callbacks/checkpointer.yaml" and "callbacks/early_stopping.yaml" is a structured schema. I will try without the structured config and report back.

Comment: I think the problem is I am validating the list of configs against a structured schema. I type the entry `callbacks` as `List[Any]`, but I get the previous error. I am using Hydra 1.1, yes.

Comment: I have updated my question with more details of what I am exactly trying to accomplish. If I remove the references to structured configs, the set up works. Let me know if you know how to address this problem using a structured schema. Thanks.